# How to group by more than on field and result is List

Tags: lambda, java-8

There is a java class:

```
 public class Test {
    private Integer parentId;
    private Integer systemId;
    private Integer id;
    private Integer weight;

    //With their setter and getter

    }
```

and there is a collection of Test class(`List<Test>`) that the its data is the following:

```
parentId    systemId      id       weight
------------------------------------------
10          100           1          200
10          100           2          300
10          300           3          400
20          400           4          200
20          400           5          600
20          500           6          6 
20          500           7          4
```

I want to group by both parentId and systemId and the result of grouping is List not to be Map.

After grouping the content of the list will be:

```
parentId    systemId      weight
---------------------------------
10             100           500  
10             300           400
20             400           800
20             500           10
```

It is important that the result of grouping is `List` not to be `Map`

Comment: Is the input to the java program a file with the format described above? Or is it a POJO?

Comment: I have a collection(List<Object>) that its data is above.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Please vote up my question

Comment: Again i have updated my question. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, I can see the use of domain class.

Comment: Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: You were so impatient and you haven't chosen any answer at the end

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this. You can use `toMap` with merge function.

```
HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Integer> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors
    .toMap(item -> new Pair<>(item.parentId, item.systemId),
           item -> item.weight, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

then convert it to list of `Test(Integer parentId, Integer systemId, Integer weight)`.

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new Test(entry.getKey().getKey(),
                                   entry.getKey().getValue(),
                                   entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As per the question description, the resultant collection has to be a `List` not a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Test>>> groupMap = test.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getParentId, Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getSystemId)));
List<Test> orderedObjects = groupMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .map(mp -> mp.getValue().stream().reduce((t1, t2) -> new Test(t1.getParentId(),
                        t1.getSystemId(), t1.getId(), t1.getWeight() + t2.getWeight())).orElse(null)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What if there's a solution to get the result directly in a `List` rather than converting from an intermediate `Map` to a `List` ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit need to first obtain the result in form of `Map` and then transform to a `List`.

Here's the solution that directly returns a `List`. The key idea is to reduce all the `Test` objects with same `parentId` and `systemId` to a resultant `Test` object that contains the sum of the `weight` field.

However, you'll have to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the `Test` class.

Following is the solution:

```
inputList = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(
            new Test(10, 100, 1, 200),
            new Test(10, 100, 2, 300),
            new Test(10, 300, 3, 400),
            new Test(20, 400, 4, 200),
            new Test(20, 400, 5, 600),
            new Test(20, 500, 6, 6),
            new Test(20, 500, 7, 4)
    )
);

BinaryOperator<Test> accumulator = (d1, d2) -> 
    new Test(d1.getParentId(), d1.getSystemId(), d1.getWeight() + d2.getWeight());

List<Test> resultList = inputList.stream()
                                .map(test1 -> inputList.stream()
                                        .filter(test2 -> !(test1.getId().equals(test2.getId())) && test1.getParentId().equals(test2.getParentId()) && test1.getSystemId().equals(test2.getSystemId()))
                                        .reduce(new Test(test1.getParentId(), test1.getSystemId(), test1.getWeight()), accumulator)
                                )
                                .distinct()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Test` class (for reference):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj == null)
        return false;

    Test d2 = (Test)obj;
    if (parentId.equals(d2.getParentId()) && systemId.equals(d2.getSystemId()) && weight.equals(d2.getWeight())) {
        if (id != null) {
            if (id.equals(d2.getId())) {
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.parentId);
    hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.systemId);
    hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.weight);
    return hash;
}
```

I'm not using the `id` field in `equals()` method as this field has been omitted in the desired output.

Comment: Honestly it isn't reasonable just use `parentId` and `SystemId` properties and ignore `id` for overridden methods. It's my idea. what happen if OP user wants to use this overridden in other place!?

Comment: I had a confusion too. But as you can see, there's no `id` field in the output. The OP should clarify if there has to be an `id` field, what should be its value from the possible set of values __multiple__ values.

Comment: @HadiJ, I understand your concern. I've modified the `equals()` method for the case when `id` has a `non-null` value. Thanks for making a point.

Answer (score 0):

What about mixed solution? You can find `Stream` solution in *@Ravindra Ranwala* answer. It works, but I think this is a little bit complicated for realize and support. I offer a little bit another solution, that looks more clear to me.

*This is function to merge `List<Test>` into `Test`. I think this is more clear to declare it separate from group logic. This time it just sum all `weight` in the given list. You can add more fields here.*

```
Function<List<Test>, Test> merge = notEmptyGroup -> {
    Test test = notEmptyGroup.iterator().next();
    int weight = notEmptyGroup.stream().map(Test::getWeight).mapToInt(w -> w).sum();
    return new Test(test.getParentId(), test.getSystemId(), weight);
};
```

*This is grouping method. This is only group logic and `merge` function that accepts all `Test` in one group to merge.*

```
public static List<Test> groupByParentIdAndSystemId(List<Test> tests, Function<List<Test>, Test> merge) {
    List<Test> results = new LinkedList<>();

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Test>>> map = tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getParentId,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getSystemId)));

    map.values().forEach(parentTests ->
            parentTests.values().forEach(systemTests ->
                    results.add(merge.apply(systemTests))));   
    results.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getParentId).thenComparingInt(Test::getSystemId));

    return results;
}
```

*This is client code:*

```
List<Test> res = groupByParentIdAndSystemId(tests, merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> groupped = input.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getParentId,Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getSystemId,Collectors.summingInt(Test::getWeight))));

Stream<List<Test>> stream = groupped.entrySet().stream().map(grouppedEntry -> {
    Integer parentId = grouppedEntry.getKey();
    return grouppedEntry
            .getValue().entrySet().stream().map(systemIdAndSummedWeight -> new Test(parentId,
                    systemIdAndSummedWeight.getKey(), systemIdAndSummedWeight.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
});

List<Test> result = stream.flatMap(List::stream).sorted(
        Comparator.comparing(Test::getParentId).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Test::getSystemId)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result

```
result.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

Test [parentId=10, systemId=100, weight=500]
Test [parentId=10, systemId=300, weight=400]
Test [parentId=20, systemId=400, weight=800]
Test [parentId=20, systemId=500, weight=10]
```